# Is there a better alternative to an STL comparator with state?

Tags: c++, stl

I have a fairly large, sophisticated algorithm that uses a `std::priority_queue`.  In some cases, I want the queue to be a min-queue, and in others, a max-queue.  So I have to provide a comparator type that does one or the other.  Since the comparator is a template parameter, it is fundamentally part of the type of the `std::priority_queue`.  So everywhere the queue is referenced, the code must know the type.

One option, of course, is to provide a custom comparator that has state, and selects between ascending and descending on each invocation of `operator()`, but I'm trying to avoid the performance overhead of having this branch for every comparison.  The other alternative that I can see is to duplicate the entire algorithm, one for sorting ascending, and the other for descending.

Is there a better alternative to this problem?

**EDIT**: Since some people seem to be so eager to help without really understanding the problem here, I'll try to elaborate a bit.

What I've implemented is an external sort algorithm (external merge sort).  The algorithm uses a `std::priority_queue` during the merge phase.  Now, the sort can either be ascending or descending.  The `std::priority_queue` comparator must be different for those two cases.  You might imagine that a simple sort algorithm could be easily parameterized to handle ascending/descending like such:

```
// psuedocode...
if (ascending) {
    if (a > b) // do something
} else {
    if (a < b) // do something
}
```

One problem with this is that the `ascending` flag has to be checked **every iteration** of the sort loop.  'jalf' suggests the compiler can "inline" this branch, but I don't think I've seen it happen, at least not with VC++ (yes, I've looked at some assembly).

Now, when using a `std::priority_queue` to keep some things in sorted order, the actual **type** of the queue is different for ascending and descending sorts (since the comparator must be different, and it is a template parameter).  So the options are:

1. Duplicate the algorithm (function) for the descending case.
2. Parameterize the algorithm on sort order and use one queue for ascending and a different one for descending.
3. Use a comparator functor with a single piece of state (isAscending) so that `operator()()` can perform the right comparison for ascending and descending.
4. Templatize the function and require the comparator be passed as a template argument.
5. Use a function pointer as the comparator template argument.

Please note that I am **not** switching between two different queue behaviors during the algorithm (as some have asked).  I am setting up the queue as a min or max queue at the start of the algorithm, and it remains as such for that particular sort.

Now to compare the options above.

Option 1 is out because of unwanted code duplication and maintenance (although it would likely produce the best performing code).

Option 2 is not desirable because of all the additional runtime checks and branching, and the unnecessary creation of a queue that will not be used.

Option 3 is more attractive because the branching is encapsulated/isolated in the comparator functor -- but still requires a runtime check for each comparison (this is fundamentally what I wanted to avoid).

Option 4 pushes the problem up one level and requires the caller to know and have access to the comparator functors -- kind of messy.

Option 5 seems pretty good -- it makes for clean code by allowing the comparator function to differ at runtime without changing the **type** of the queue.  The decision logic does not have to be exposed to the caller (as it would with option 4).

The only negative I can see with option 5 is that the compiler **may** not be able to inline the call through the function pointer -- but in my case it did, because the called function was defined locally in the same translation unit.  If it were not inlined, I'm guessing option 3 would have been better, but in my case performance was better with option 5.

Also, after I realized that option 5 was possible (I didn't at first), it occurred to me that using function pointers instead of functors is probably not done much, and I suspect people sometimes jump through hoops to use functors (as I would have had to), when a function pointer may make for much cleaner code (particularly when performance isn't a concern).

Comment: ...one branch is a performance overhead?! Did your profiler say this?

Comment: No, I haven't profiled yet. Let's just say I understand the algorithm enough to know that a branch on *every* comparison will be a problem. The comparisons will already be the hot spot in this code, and it is performance critical.

Comment: I don't understand. As you just said, the comparator is a template parameter, which means it's fixed, and there's no branching needed. Or do you need the *same* priority queue to toggle between being a min and a max queue? (which would cause a whole lot of other problems)

Comment: @Tabber: also no, you may understand the algorithm, but you don't understand whether or not that branch will be a performance problem. Don't make assumptions about performance. *Never*. Especially not if you care about efficient code. Nothing is true, apart from what your profiler tells you. Do you know how many other instructions are going to be in between each comparison? Do you know how well the CPU predicts branches and reschedules instructions to hide branch latency? Unless you've profiled, then no, you don't. And if you don't know these things, then you don't know if the branch matters.

Comment: I want to be able to call this function for both ascending and descending sorting modes -- this is a function parameter. I do not need the same queue to toggle (does that even make sense?). I'm well aware of the obscurities of predicting performance. I just profiled my function, and as I expected, 70% of the execution time is spent in the comparator's `operator()`. I simply can't make it slower with a branch.

Comment: FYI, execution time is ~20% longer with the check in the comparator function -- this is unacceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use templates

```
template <typename Comparator>
void algo()
{
  std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, Comparator> pqueue;
  ...
}
```

-- edit
I read your edit but I still don't really get what's bothering you. You say

```
Option 4 pushes the problem up one level and requires the
caller to know and have access to the comparator functors 
-- kind of messy.
```

Anyway the caller will have to choose between ascending or not.
And, of course, it is not necessary for him to know which comparator type to use:

```
void algo_ascending() {
  algo<Ascending_Comparator>();
}
void algo_descending() {
  algo<Descending_Comparator>();
}
```

Or even

```
void algo(bool ascending) {
  if (ascending)
     algo<Ascending_Comparator>();
  else
     algo<Descending_Comparator>();
}
```

Comment: You are right. Don't know why I thought option 4 was messy. Man, this was a horrible question to begin with, and I don't think it has any potential to help anyone else, but SO won't let me delete it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a comparator which has state then you can not change that state because the comparator is copied by the queue. In order to change the state of your comparator after your queue was constructed you can use shared state.

However the state should not be used to alter the result of comparisons after elements are added to the queue. This would probably cause weird behavior of the queue.

```
struct shared_state_t
{
 int number;
};

struct compare_t
{
 bool operator <(const record_t &left, const record_t &right) const { left < right; }
 tr1::shared_ptr<shared_state_t> shared;
};

void func()
{
 tr1::shared_ptr<shared_state_t> state(new shared_state_t());
 state->number = 42;
 compare_t comp;
 comp.shared = state;
 std::priority_queue<record_t, vector<record_t>, compare_t> queue(comp);
 // do something with queue
 state->number = 999;
 // compare object of queue is aware of the new state
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that I'm changing state during the lifetime of the queue -- I am not.  It's on each invocation of the algorithm.

Comment: @Tabber: then why would you need to branch at all? Just create a `priority_queue<T, min_comparator>` and a `priority_queue<T, max_comparator>`, and use whichever does what you need.

Comment: But then I have to check a flag before each access to the queue, in addition to creating two queue objects, when I only need one.  I guess I just have to templatize the whole algorithm on the stinking comparator class... this is the only way to avoid *many costly runtime checks* to see which direction I'm currently sorting.

Comment: @Tabber33: that doesn't make sense. You said you never need to change state during the lifetime of a queue. Which means that you *do* need more than one queue if you plan to actually *use* both ascending and descending ordering. It sounds like you're confused about something pretty fundamental. Back up a bit. Show us some code illustrating what you need to do.

Comment: I don't think I'm confused about anything fundamental.  I updated my question to elaborate a bit -- perhaps my original question was misleading -- and now I've spent **way** too much time on this simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

`std::priority_queue` takes a comparator object in its constructor. Take the object as a function parameter and pass it to the constructor. Each call will create a different container depending on the parameter. So the branch is only at the time of construction.

```
template<class C>
void the_algorithm(const C& compare)
{
    std::priority_queue<Type> q(compare);
    // ...
}

bool this_before_that(const Type& op1, const Type& op2);

// ...
{
    the_algorithm(this_before_that);
    the_algorithm(ThatBeforeThis_Functor());
}
```

The branching count here is merely in the order of calls to the algorithm.

Comment: Not true.  Try to code this, and I think you'll see why this is wrong.  The *type* of the comparator must be the same.  So the branch must be inside the comparator function.

Comment: @Tabber33 the type changes depending on the comparator, yes. But I understood you don't need to share the same container for difference comparison modes. Have the algorithm work with a single type of container depending on how it was called. what's wrong here?

Comment: I don't understand what you are suggeting here... could you show some sample code?  `...a single type of container depending on how it was called` sounds like you are suggeting the algorithm function being a template with the comparison object type a template parameter?

Comment: @Tabber33 yes. and now i see that someone has already suggested exactly that. only thing is, if you take the object as a parameter then it's somewhat easier to invoke the algorithm with primitive functions.

Comment: Indeed, but that doesn't solve my problem, which is getting the check out of the comparison function.

Comment: I think I just figured out how to do this... by using a function instead of a functor. I can declare the template parameter as a pointer to function and pass a different pointer to the queue constructor...  If you post another answer with that suggestion, I can accept it.

Comment: @Tabber33, if you have a solution that isn't represented by any other answers, you can answer your own question.